# parameter value is not getting entered in text field using VB script for UFT 12.02

Tags: qtp, sapui5, hp-uft, siebel

parameter value is not getting entered in text field using VB script for UFT 12.02. though the text field is getting highlighted still when using set property value is not getting entered. Can anybody tell why it is happening
[image][image]

Comment: Are you getting any error during execution. If so, kindly update the details of the error

Comment: @mulla- I m not getting any error text field is getting highlighted however when am trying to enter text in that field text is not getting entered: Please refer below line of codes:    Browser(oBrowser).Page(oPg).WebEdit(oWEdit).Highlight... 2) Browser(oBrowser).Page(oPg).WebEdit(oWEdit).set "Naveen". Filed is getting highlighted but text Naveen is not  getting populated in that field..

Comment: try setting the values using sendkeys

Comment: @mulla-- ok.. will let you know and thanks for reposne

Comment: Instead of `.Set`, try using `WebEdit(oEdit).Type` to set the value

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't add "Test Parameters" from "Action Call Properties" ? At that case it overrides action input parameter to test input parameter

Answer (score 1):

@ridvanzoro: issue is not related to parameter.  Actually i was not able to entr the value as it was identifying as webelement before entering text value and once we click on that text element then only it was getting enabled.. so i got 2 menthods to resolve either i can use sendkeys tab to enable that or i can use click properties of webedit so it is getting enabled and now i am abke to enter the text..